# Como faço para fazer um if condicional comparando apenas com os 2 últimos algarismos?

Tags: vb.net

Estou fazendo um projeto em Visual Basic porém quando o usuário digitar uma sequência de caracteres que serão 5 o máximo ex: UF052 quero fazer um `if` onde será comparado.

```
If textbox1 = "UF052" the
  Comando
End if
```

Porém não quero comparar todos os caracteres e sim apenas o 52 poderia ser UG152 que ainda sim cairia no `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Pode comparar os dois últimos caracteres da sua `string` sem a manipular e [criar uma nova `string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473831/1242661):

```
If(textBox1(textBox1.Length - 2) = "5"C And textBox1(textBox1.Length - 1) = "2"C)
    Comando
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o `Substring`. Exemplo:

```
Dim text As string = "Olá mundo!"
Dim teste As Boolean = text.Substring(text.Length - 2) = "o!"

Console.WriteLine(teste) //True
Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(text.Length - 2)) //o!
```

Melhor ainda seria usar o `EndsWith`

```
Dim text As string = "Olá mundo!"
Dim teste As Boolean = text.EndsWith("o!")

Console.WriteLine(teste)
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, use o "InStr" que vai dar certo também. Segue exemplo:

```
if InStr("UF052", "52") > 0 then 
    Comando
End if
```

ou caso queira pegar somente os dois últimos caracteres:

```
if InStr(Right("UF052", 2), "52") > 0 then 
    Comando
End if
```

Comment: Podia melhorar a condição passando ao `InStr()` a [posição onde quer começar a pesquisa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04206edx(v=vs.110).aspx) (neste caso os últimos dois dígitos da `string`).

Comment: sim, se a string dele vier sempre "UF052"  ele pode impor a posição. Exemplo: InStr(Right("UF052", 2), "52")

Comment: Segundo o OP, ele quer verificar sempre os dois últimos caracteres da `string` daí a minha sugestão. Neste caso não é problemático porque, segundo o OP, a `string` tem no máximo 5 caracteres, logo o impacto na performance é mínimo.

Comment: Alterei meu comentário...

Comment: sim, na verdade o UF sempre terá este valor vou definir UF ja no inicial o usuario ira digitar só por exemplo 654 ou outro valor, consigo fazer com variaveis tbm?, pq não vou saber qual o valor q o usuario irá digitar, terá um textbox2 que aparecerá esses UF*** a certo momento então quando chegar esse UF*** igual ao do usuario entraria no true.

Comment: Tem sim IxxtomxxI, no lugar da string você coloca uma variável do tipo string.